# Cannot press more then one button or an already pressed button Selenium

Tags: selenium

I'm using this code to move element by offset

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
      builder.moveToElement(element).clickAndHold(element).moveByOffset(xOffset,yOffset).perform();
```

It works fine when only used once but when I make it a function

```
public void fun(int xOffset,int yOffset, String elementId){
       WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(id));
       Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
       builder.moveToElement(element).clickAndHold(element).moveByOffset(xOffset,yOffset).perform();
}
fun(100,0,"main_element");
fun(0,100,"main_element");
```

And call it with multiple elements I get the error `Cannot press more then one button or an already pressed button`

Comment: I'm not a Selenium expert, but shouldn't you `release()` somewhere?

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code, where you use it multiple times?

Comment: Edited the code. With first call I check whether I can move left on the element and the second one checks if I can move up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possibilities that could trigger this problem:

- your elementIds are not unique
- when you use your fun method, you are handing over the same elementId again and again (best post your code, maybe there's a mistake in a loop or something)

If you use the same elementId but just change the offsets, this won't help you.
After each clickAndHold(element) you need to release this button. Otherwise, as the error message is telling you, the button is regarded as "already pressed". -> have a look at the description of the method [here](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html)

So what can you do (depends on what you actually want to achieve with clicking the button):

1) don't `clickAndHold()` but just `click()`

```
 builder.moveToElement(element).click(element).moveByOffset(xOffset,yOffset).perform();
```

2) after `clickAndHold()`, use  `release()`

```
builder.moveToElement(element).clickAndHold(element).moveByOffset(xOffset,yOffset).perform();
builder.release(element).perform();
```

Comment: Yes I do hand the same elementId over and over again but the offsets are different.

Comment: Used the second solution as I needed to create drag effect. Thanks!